# inserting data from multiple tables into one separate table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

First of all, I know MySQL is a depreciated language, but my supervisor insists I use it.

I have three tables in my database. They are : *"students", "tutors", "match"*. When I find a run the below query($query2) I am checking the make sure all the criteria in that query is perfectly matched.

When it is perfectly matched I want to insert the following into the match table:

```
"insert into match (tutor_id, student_id, school_id) values ('$tutor_id','$student_id','$school_id')";
```

The "match" table contains the columns:

```
match_id(auto incremented), tutor_id, student_id, school_id
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if(mysql_query($query2)){
    $check_availability =  "select * 
                            from tutors, students 
                            where tutor_availability = '$student_availability'
                            AND (tutor_subject_1 = '$student_subject_1'
                            OR tutor_subject_1 = '$student_subject_2'
                            OR tutor_subject_2 = '$student_subject_2'
                            OR tutor_subject_2 = '$student_subject_1')";    

    $run_5 = mysql_query($check_availability);

    if(mysql_num_rows($run_5)>0) {

        echo  "<script>alert('we have a match')</script>";
        my_sql_query($query3) =  "insert into match (tutor_id, student_id, school_id) values ('$tutor_id','$student_id','$school_id')";

        mysql_query($query3);
    } else{
        echo  "<script>alert('no match found')</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: MySQL is in no way a deprecated language, php mysql_* functions are

Comment: then whats your problem...?

Comment: The values will not go into the "match" table

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is wrong:

```
my_sql_query($query3) =  "insert into match (tutor_id, student_id, school_id) values ('$tutor_id','$student_id','$school_id')";
```

The function name is spelled wrong and the parameter shouldn't be `$query3` but the actual query:

```
mysql_query("insert into match (tutor_id, student_id, school_id) values ('$tutor_id','$student_id','$school_id')");
```

Comment: Sorry that was a small mistake. Corrected it, but its still not working

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to insert the output of the previous query into the database.

change

```
$check_availability =  "select * 
                        from tutors, students 
                        where tutor_availability = '$student_availability'
                        AND (tutor_subject_1 = '$student_subject_1'
                        OR tutor_subject_1 = '$student_subject_2'
                        OR tutor_subject_2 = '$student_subject_2'
                        OR tutor_subject_2 = '$student_subject_1')";
```

to

```
$check_availability =  "insert into match (tutor_id, student_id, school_id) 
                        select tutors.id, students.id, students.school_id 
                        from tutors, students 
                        where tutor_availability = '$student_availability'
                        AND (tutor_subject_1 = '$student_subject_1'
                        OR tutor_subject_1 = '$student_subject_2'
                        OR tutor_subject_2 = '$student_subject_2'
                        OR tutor_subject_2 = '$student_subject_1')";
```

Comment: With this piece of code it no longer finds a match for some reason? I thought it would work for sure

Comment: @bano590 - this is an insert query, not a select. If you want to check for matches, then you would have to run your select, then loop through the rows and then insert.

Comment: what is the best way to do that in this case? I am fairly new to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the row to get the values to insert:

```
if(mysql_query($query2)){
    $check_availability =  "select * 
                            from tutors, students 
                            where tutor_availability = '$student_availability'
                            AND (tutor_subject_1 = '$student_subject_1'
                            OR tutor_subject_1 = '$student_subject_2'
                            OR tutor_subject_2 = '$student_subject_2'
                            OR tutor_subject_2 = '$student_subject_1')";    

    $run_5 = mysql_query($check_availability);

    if(mysql_num_rows($run_5)>0) {

        echo  "<script>alert('we have a match')</script>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_5)) {
            $tutor_id = $row['tutor_id'];
            $student_id = $row['student_id'];
            $school_id = $row['school_id'];
            mysql_query("insert into match (tutor_id, student_id, school_id) values ('$tutor_id','$student_id','$school_id')");
        }

    } else{
        echo  "<script>alert('no match found')</script>";
    }
}
```

I don't know the exact field names, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: what is the query $res in this case?

Comment: @bano590 $res should be $run_5. Sorry, I corrected that in the example code.

Comment: you actually got all the field names right, but it's still not working

Comment: Does the select query return any results? Try a simple `print mysql_num_rows($run_5);` to see if the query is ok.

Comment: the only error that appeared is: Notice: Undefined index: school_id in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/VTP2/VTPblog.php on line 253. I have since taken out the "school_id" but the query still doesn't work?

Comment: Make sure all queries return results. Use `print mysql_error()` to see if there is something wrong with the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using mysql_fetch_row($run_5) and change the select query to only pull out tutor_id, student_id and school_id.

```
if(mysql_query($query2)){
$check_availability =  "select t.tutor_id, s.student_id, t.school_id
                        from t.tutors, s.students 
                        where t.tutor_availability = '$student_availability'
                        AND (t.tutor_subject_1 = '$student_subject_1'
                        OR t.tutor_subject_1 = '$student_subject_2'
                        OR t.tutor_subject_2 = '$student_subject_2'
                        OR t.tutor_subject_2 = '$student_subject_1')";    

$run_5 = mysql_query($check_availability);

if(mysql_num_rows($run_5)>0) {

    echo  "<script>alert('we have a match')</script>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($run_5)) {
        $tutor_id = $row[0];
        $student_id = $row[1];
        $school_id = $row[2];
        mysql_query("insert into match (tutor_id, student_id, school_id) values ('$tutor_id','$student_id','$school_id')");
    }

} else{
    echo  "<script>alert('no match found')</script>";
}
```

}

Comment: I have tried this code, it's the closest I've got to the answer I want. The problem seems to be in the line: mysql_query("insert into match (tutor_id, student_id, school_id) values ('$tutor_id','$student_id','$school_id')");